# Database constraints to ignore soft-deleted entries when evaluating uniqueness

Tags: swift, constraints, vapor

I have a `User` model that users can use to create accounts in my Vapor (Swift) application.
`User` implements the `Migration` protocol as follows:

```
static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
    return Database.create(self, on: conn) { (builder) in
        try addProperties(to: builder)
        builder.unique(on: \.email)
    }
}
```

Now, this works just fine, but if a user *(soft-)deletes* their account and tries to sign up with the same email address again, they cannot, because the email has already been used.

How can I tell the `builder` to ignore values from deleted entries when evaluating uniqueness?

Comment: Do you have any constraints set on your database? E.g. unique `email`? The validation only checks for a valid e-mail address to be passed and the password to not be empty.

Comment: Afaik the soft delete doesn't remove the row from the table, so the sql constraint still keeps on failing.

Comment: @ErikTerwan ugh, wrong code snippet. Updated my post.

Comment: @ErikTerwan the whole point of soft-deletion is to not *actually* remove the data but only mark it as removed.

Comment: Yeah a soft delete doesn't remove the row from the table, so it's logical that the constraint keeps on failing. This is [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/fluent/models/#soft-delete)

Comment: Like I said, that's how it's *supposed* to be. And now I need a way to make exceptions for the uniqueness.

Comment: Yeah of course, i get what a soft delete is, there's just different ways of handling them; e.g. use a separate table for them, or as Vapor does it, with a timestamp. The database itself has no knowledge of this, so the constraint fails.

Comment: Hmm I thought there might be a flag or a custom closure in which I could make exceptions.

Comment: You can't actually tell `builder` to ignore values from deleted entries, since the builder just adds native mysql/postgres constraint to your table. You would have to do this manually when adding a new user, e.g. query the full table, including deleted entries, and go from there.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks for the hint! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually tell `builder` to ignore values from deleted entries, since the builder just adds native mysql/postgres constraint to your table.

You would have to do this manually when adding a new user, e.g. query the full table, including deleted entries, and go from there.

Comment: Coming from the other direction: I thought about doing `toBeDeletedUser.email = "_" + toBeDeletedUser.email` just before deleting it so that the user can sign up with the same email again. However, this works only once. Is there a good practice for this type of solution? Like append random chars or sth.?

Comment: Yeah you could go in that direction, but isn't it nicer to show a message to the user like: 'You used to have an account on this e-mail address, do you want to override this account or reactivate it?' And then just permanently remove if they chose override, or undo delete when reactivating.

Comment: Also a nice idea. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Otherwise i would add a timestamp instead of underscore; e.g. `email@me.com?12345678..`

Comment: Ah, timestamp is probably the most reliable, yes.